# If $a,b$ commute in $G$, have finite order, $⟨a⟩\cap⟨b⟩\neq ⟨1⟩$ and neither is contained in the other, describe $|ab|$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, examples-counterexamples

If $a,b$ commute in $G$, have finite order, $⟨a⟩\neq ⟨b⟩$, and $⟨a⟩\cap⟨b⟩\neq ⟨1⟩$, describe $|ab|$.

If $\langle a \rangle \cap \langle b \rangle = \langle 1 \rangle$ then $o(ab)=\hbox{lcm} (o(a), o(b))$. If $\langle a \rangle = \langle b \rangle$ there are plenty of counterexamples where it isn't true. If $\langle a \rangle \subset \langle b \rangle$ it is again easy to provide a counterexample (a cyclic group).
  In the other cases, however, it seems that $o(ab)=\hbox{lcm} (o(a), o(b))$ always.

However, I have a hunch that it is false; could you give a counterexample or a method to unravel this problem?

Comment: What does the "$\km$" mean?

Comment: I don't recall adding that hypothesis.

Comment: I checked the edit history. I did not add the hypothesis that the group is finite. You did.

Comment: You should **not** add hypotheses when you already have an answer in order to disqualify the answer without **clearly** indicating that you changed the problem. By adding the hypothesis "neither contained in the other", you have made it appear that my answer completely missed that point, thus inviting corrections and downvotes on me.

Comment: I'm sorry Arturo, I apologize, I hadn't thought of that, I was too busy thinking about the problem. Thank you for pointing that out

Comment: @Shaun yes but then I deleted it and after a while I found it again. Since you were the last one to edit I thought it was you, I apologize.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot conclude that the order is the least common multiple in this situation.

For an easy example, consider $G=C_2\times C_3$, let $a=(1,1)$ and $b=(0,2)$. Then $\langle b\rangle \subseteq \langle a\rangle$ but they are not equal, $o(a) = 6$, $o(b)=3$, and $ab=(1,0)$ has order $2$.  (This is just $C_6$, with $a$ a generator and $b=a^2$).

---

**Added.** The problem has been changed to exclude either group being contained in the other. This only requires an easy tweak: take $G=C_2\times C_3\times C_2$, $a=(1,1,0)$, $b=(0,2,1)$. Then $o(a)=6$, $o(b)=6$, $ab=(1,0,1)$ has order $2$, and neither subgroup is contained in the other.

---

In general, the best you can say is that:
$$\begin{align*}
\frac{\mathrm{lcm}(o(a),o(b))}{\gcd(o(a),o(b))} &\Bigm| \frac{\mathrm{lcm}(o(a),o(b))}{|\langle a\rangle\cap \langle b\rangle|}\\
\strut\\
\frac{\mathrm{lcm}(o(a),o(b))}{|\langle a\rangle\cap \langle b\rangle|}&
\Bigm| o(ab)\\
\strut\\
o(ab) &\Bigm| \mathrm{lcm}(o(a),o(b)).
\end{align*}$$

---

The key here is that you can always express an element of finite order as a product of pairwise commuting elements of prime power order, pairwise coprime. To see this, suppose $x$ has order $ab$ with $\gcd(a,b)=1$. Then there exist integers $r$ and $t$ such that $1 = ar+bt$. Note that $\gcd(r,b)=\gcd(r,t)=\gcd(a,t)=1$. We have that $x = (x^{ar})(x^{bt})$. Now, $x^a$ has order $b$, and $\gcd(r,b)=1$, so $o(x^{ar}) = o((x^a)^r) = b/\gcd(b,r) = b$. Symmetrically, $o(x^{bt}) = a$. So $x$ is a product of an element of order $a$ and an element of order $b$. Lather, rinse, and repeat (or do induction on the number of prime factors) to get that if $x$ has order $n$, and $n=p_1^{a_1}\cdots p_r^{a_r}$ is the prime factorization of $n$, then $x$ can be written as $x=x_1\cdots x_n$ with $o(x_i)=p_i^{a_i}$.

So now think about your $a$ and $b$; primes that only occur in one of $o(a)$ and $o(b)$ will occur in $o(ab)$; and more generally a bit of work shows that if the highest power of $p$ that divides $o(a)$ is different from the highest power of $p$ that divides $o(b)$, then the highest power of $p$ that divides $o(ab)$ is the maximum of the two (giving you the "correct" exponent for the least common multiple). So the key lies in situations where the highest power of $p$ that shows up in $o(a)$ and in $o(b)$ is equal. Clearly, you can try to arrange things so that the $p$-part of $a$ and the $p$-part of $b$ cancel out (or just partially cancel out) but the rest of the parts are disjoint, so that you get $o(ab)$ strictly smaller than $\mathrm{lcm}(o(a),o(b))$, while also ensuring that neither of $\langle a\rangle$ and $\langle b\rangle$ contain each other. That is what I did: the $2$-parts of $a$ and $b$ don't interact, but the $3$-parts cancel each other.

Comment: Thank you Arturo, but I had forgotten to add the hypothesis of mutual non-inclusion (added now). I have been trying in vain to find counterexamples in just this case (and I have started to question the existence of such a group). I would really like to know a way to produce such counterexamples (if they exist).

Comment: @TheFootprint: Yes, you changed the problem without noting the change, thus making it seem that I missed a hypothesis and my answer was wrong. Thank you for that. I've added an example in which neither is contained in the other.

Comment: Thanks, this is just what I was looking for! Sorry again for the sneaky edit.

Comment: What if we *add* the condition $o(a)=o(b)=p^n$, $p$ prime? Can we conclude that $o(ab)=[o(a),o(b)]=p^n$?

Comment: @TheFootprint: Did you see the final paragraph? That's *precisely* the situation in which you cannot conclude that. You can make the order anything between $p$ and $p^n$ (given your requirement that the subgroups not be disjoint). E.g., take $G=C_{p^i}\times C_{p^n}\times C_{p^i}$, with $1\leq i\lt n$, $a=(1,1,0)$, $b=(0,p^n-1,1)$.

Comment: I got confused because I wrongly assumed that the intersection of two mutually non-included subgroups must have order strictly less than either (and therefore didn't see how I could cancel out the $p^n$ term). I clearly see that it is false now, but I still cannot wrap my head around it; I must delve deeper into the theory (especially direct products). Thank you for your patience.

Comment: @TheFootprint: Yes, the intersection of two subgroups, neither of which is included in the other, is strictly smaller than either. But that is neither here nor there. The only thing that you are excluding is the possibility that $ab$ be trivial.

Comment: I know this is ridiculous, but isn't the order of $(a)\cap(b)$ equal to $p^n$ in your example? Just like the subgroups generated by $a$ and $b$. Edit: of course not, it's $p^{n-i}$. Sorry

Comment: @TheFootprint: No; if the order were the same as each, then the two would be equal. The intersection has order $p^{n-i}$. Try it with $n=2$ and $i=1$. The intersection is the subgroup generated by $(0,p,0)$.

Comment: Yes, I've edited my comment just before you posted yours. I have such a lacking knowledge of direct subgroups. But I've learned the lesson now, sorry for bothering you with such trivial things.

Comment: I would like to prove the following. For every group $G$, given $a,b \in G$ with my hypotheses plus $o(a)=o(b)=p^n$, there exist $x,y$ such that $⟨x⟩=⟨a⟩, ⟨y⟩=⟨b⟩$ and $o(xy)<p^n$. Is it true?

Comment: @Footprint: This is too far into comments. If you have a different question, ask it as a different question, not hidden in comments.